# Error with pg_trgm indexes while upgrading postgres on RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-extensions

I want to upgrade the major version of my prod Postgres RDS database, from 11.16 to 12.11.
I restored a snapshot to do a dry run.
When trying to modify the version on AWS, I have the following error:

```
pg_restore: from TOC entry 5375; 1259 180582003 INDEX my_index my_database
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: permission denied for schema publicf2iwen5v79e7a7ugjf2zdrpvhvpmr9bc
Command was:
-- For binary upgrade, must preserve pg_class oids
SELECT pg_catalog.binary_upgrade_set_next_index_pg_class_oid('180582003'::pg_catalog.oid);

CREATE INDEX "my_index" ON "publicf2iwen5v79e7a7ugjf2zdrpvhvpmr9bc"."my_table" USING "gin" ("upper"("my_column") "publicf2iwen5v79e7a7ugjf2zdrpvhvpmr9bc"."gin_trgm_ops");
```

When removing this index, and the other 3 trgm indexes, the upgrade works fine.

I've checked the owner of the extension, it's the same as the other ones, and I don't see any difference between those indexes and other ones, except they're from `pg_trgm`

Have you any idea on how to fix this? Obviously I would like to avoid deleting these indexes on my real prod DB before upgrading the version.

The same problem occurs when upgrading from 12 to 13